# Bluetooth File Transfer

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am developing a Bluetooth application based on the Bluetooth Chat Example from the [Android Developer Site](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html). I need to do File Transfer via Bluetooth. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: nice question, voting u up, as i also got work for similar task,,

Answer (score 9):

In case of transferring the files you can make an explicit call to ACTION_SEND using intents as shown below.

You can send a file to a paired device through obex in a couple of ways:

With the `ACTION_SEND` intent, that will popup a menu with the application that can handle the file type you want to send, from which the user will need to select bluetooth, and then the device.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); i.setType("image/jpeg");    
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("/sdcard/file.jpg")); 
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send Image"));
```

I think this will help u . :)

Comment: File sourceFile = new File("//mnt/sdcard/TviderFB.apk");
         Intent intent = new Intent();
         intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
         intent.setType("image/jpeg");
         intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
         Uri.fromFile(sourceFile));
         ctx.startActivity(intent);

Comment: i add this code for blue tooth file transfer this code is working fine in my app

Comment: Hussain i am not able to ask and add my answer in stakoverflow can please help..?

Comment: Just take a look at it.. U can know y u r not able to ask question or answer it.http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this/86998#86998

Answer (score 4):

Follow these steps:

1. Read your source file to a byte array (buffer)
2. Call the write method of your chat service instance passing the bytes to be sent:

   ```
   // mChatService is your Bluetooth chat service  
   mChatService.write(buffer);
   ```
3. Edit the Handler for `MESSAGE_WRITE` and `MESSAGE_READ` cases

Comment: hi there,
@Mr Bo Persson, and Sajjad sjj
.
i m voting up your answer, i think this gonna help me out for my requirement, i want to send a object(of myDataType) to the scaned devices, and also read on receiving side, so would you kindly elaborate this techniques, as i have spent less time with android programming so this may seems tough for me, Thanks in Advance..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938237/hiding-permission-intent-in-android/6938298#6938298