# Hiding permission intent in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, permissions

As we know, Android OS has some restrictions to operate device hardwares programmetically, like it shows intent to user which requires YES for return true to the specific intent, i-e:

```
Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
```

I want to hide this intent from user, and want to return true, as if user click YES,
is there any way to code like this ?

I am not asking about turn ON bluetooth without permission, like( `myBlueToothAdapter.enable()` works) I have to hide another intent which works same as this one..

Hope someone can guide me to the proper way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you started the intent activity! what do you mean you want to hide it?

Comment: i want to hide this, means, i don't want to show it to the user, n just assuming that user click YES for this intent, there must be a way to do this..

Answer (score 3):

The security mechanisms in place for Android would inherently forbid this.

Comment: I'm simply saying that the reason the security permissions exist is to **prevent** the very thing that you are trying to attempt, as what you are attempting is **WITHOUT** the user specifically giving the ok. It's an _inherent design_ of the permissions model.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite understand you are asking. It seems that you don't want to use the built-in `Intent` that requests the user to turn on the bluetooth radio. If this is the case, you are saying you want to have your own intent (activity) that ask the user to turn on/off bluetooth? You can use `BluetoothAdapter.enable()` in your activity to do this. OR you can use that API to turn on bluetooth without asking the user.