# Choose file from downloads folder -> send it over bluetooth

Tags: android, file, button, bluetooth

I have a problem that I've broken down into two main parts.

1) Click button to pop up downloads folder. Choose a file from the downloads folder.

2) Take that file that you just chose. Send it to a paired device via bluetooth.

The bluetooth portion I believe won't be that bad given the resources and examples on here.

But #1 I am having trouble figuring out how to tackle (kinda new to android). Are there any good tutorials/docs/links for accessing the downloads folder, picking a file and then using that file for later use for things such as file transfer/etc?

Thanks

Comment: Have you googled any posts and tutorials? If yes then please ask a more specific question, if no - then that's the thing you should do every time before asking a question on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File selection on android -

http://code.google.com/p/android-file-dialog/

[How to use intent for choosing file browser to select file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923760/how-to-use-intent-for-choosing-file-browser-to-select-file)

Whichever method you use you will need to get a file path back. Then you will use that path for the next part of your question, how to send a file via Bluetooth

[Bluetooth File Transfer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326716/bluetooth-file-transfer)

[How to send file from Android device to other device through Bluetooth by code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227498/how-to-send-file-from-android-device-to-other-device-through-bluetooth-by-code)

Always do research before you ask - you will get more up votes and better answers if you do